# How can I make the blinking cursor disappear after 3 seconds at the end of the animation?

Tags: css, frontend

I have this HTML

```
      <div class=typewriter>
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      </div>
```

and this CSS

```
.typewriter {
    display: inline-block;
}

.typewriter h1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: .15em solid black;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    letter-spacing: .15em;
    animation:
        typing 3.5s steps(30, end),
        blink .75s step-end 0s infinite;
}

@keyframes typing {
    from {
        width: 0;
    }

    to {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@keyframes blink {

    0%,
    100% {
        border-color: black;
    }

    50% {
        border-color: transparent;
    }
}
```

The animation is almost perfect, but I need the cursor to disappear after 3 seconds at the end of animation.

How can I do it? Also, there's anything I could improve?

I look at other questions like this one, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add another keyframe.

```css
.typewriter {
  display: inline-block;
}

.typewriter h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .15em solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  animation:
    typing 3.5s steps(30, end),
    blink .75s step-end 0s infinite,
    end 3s 3.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }

  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes blink {

  0%,
  100% {
    border-color: black;
  }

  50% {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes end {
  to {
    border-right: 0 solid transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

In this example, I have added `end`. After 3 seconds (feel free to change it), the color of `border-right` should be transparent.

Comment: What does this "forwards" do? Also, the cursor is slowing disappearing at the end (it's like being gray before it becomes transparent). How can I make it suddenly disappear at the end, without being gray before becomes transparent?

Comment: Related to `forwards`, please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode#forwards. If you do not want an animation for the ending, use `end 0s 6s forwards;` instead.